# "Pointer being freed was not allocated" happen on mac but not on window7

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, calloc

I am doing an exercise on a book, changing the words in a sentence into pig latin. The code works fine in window 7, but when I compiled it in mac, the error comes out.

After some testings, the error comes from there. I don't understand the reason of this problem. I am using dynamic memories for all the pointers and I have also added the checking of null pointer.

```
while (walker != NULL && *walker != NULL){
    free(**walker); 
    free(*walker);
    free(walker); 

    walker++;
}
```

**Full source code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define inputSize 81
void getSentence(char sentence [], int size);
int countWord(char sentence[]);
char ***parseSentence(char sentence[], int *count);
char *translate(char *world);
char *translateSentence(char ***words, int count);

int main(void){
    /* Local definition*/
    char sentence[inputSize];
    int wordsCnt;
    char ***head;
    char *result;

    getSentence(sentence, inputSize);
    head = parseSentence(sentence, &wordsCnt);

    result = translateSentence(head, wordsCnt);
    printf("\nFinish the translation: \n");
    printf("%s", result);


    return 0;
}

void getSentence(char sentence [81], int size){
    char *input = (char *)malloc(size);
    int length;

    printf("Input the sentence to big latin : ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(input, size, stdin);

    // do not copy the return character at inedx of length - 1
    // add back delimater 
    length = strlen(input);
    strncpy(sentence, input, length-1);
    sentence[length-1]='\0';

    free(input);
}

int countWord(char sentence[]){
    int count=0;

    /*Copy string for counting */
    int length = strlen(sentence);
    char *temp = (char *)malloc(length+1);
    strcpy(temp, sentence);

    /* Counting */
    char *pToken = strtok(temp, " ");
    char *last = NULL;
    assert(pToken == temp);
    while (pToken){
        count++;

        pToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    free(temp);
    return count;
}
char ***parseSentence(char sentence[], int *count){
    // parse the sentence into string tokens
    // save string tokens as a array
    // and assign the first one element to the head
    char *pToken;
    char ***words;
    char *pW;

    int noWords = countWord(sentence);
    *count = noWords;

    /* Initiaze array */
    int i;
    words = (char ***)calloc(noWords+1, sizeof(char **));
    for (i = 0; i< noWords; i++){
        words[i] = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
    }

    /* Parse string */
    // first element
    pToken = strtok(sentence, " ");

    if (pToken){
        pW = (char *)malloc(strlen(pToken)+1);
        strcpy(pW, pToken);
        **words = pW;
        /***words = pToken;*/

        // other elements
        for (i=1; i<noWords; i++){
            pToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
            pW = (char *)malloc(strlen(pToken)+1);
            strcpy(pW, pToken);
            **(words + i) = pW;
            /***(words + i) = pToken;*/
        }
    }

    /* Loop control */
    words[noWords] = NULL;


    return words;
}

/* Translate a world into big latin */
char *translate(char *word){
    int length = strlen(word);
    char *bigLatin = (char *)malloc(length+3);

    /* translate the word into pig latin */
    static char *vowel = "AEIOUaeiou";
    char *matchLetter;
    matchLetter = strchr(vowel, *word);
    // consonant
    if (matchLetter == NULL){
        // copy the letter except the head
        // length = lenght of string without delimiter
        // cat the head and add ay
        // this will copy the delimater,
        strncpy(bigLatin, word+1, length);
        strncat(bigLatin, word, 1);
        strcat(bigLatin, "ay");
    }
    // vowel
    else {
        // just append "ay"
        strcpy(bigLatin, word);
        strcat(bigLatin, "ay");
    }


    return bigLatin;
}

char *translateSentence(char ***words, int count){
    char *bigLatinSentence;
    int length = 0;
    char *bigLatinWord;

    /* calculate the sum of the length of the words */
    char ***walker = words;
    while (*walker){
        length += strlen(**walker);
        walker++;
    }

    /* allocate space for return string */
    // one space between 2 words
    // numbers of space required = 
    // length of words
    // + (no. of words * of a spaces (1) -1 ) 
    // + delimater
    // + (no. of words * ay (2) )
    int lengthOfResult = length + count + (count * 2);
    bigLatinSentence = (char *)malloc(lengthOfResult);
    // trick to initialize the first memory 
    strcpy(bigLatinSentence, "");

    /* Translate each word */
    int i;
    char *w;
    for (i=0; i<count; i++){
        w = translate(**(words + i));
        strcat(bigLatinSentence, w);
        strcat(bigLatinSentence, " ");
        assert(w != **(words + i));
        free(w);
    }


    /* free memory of big latin words */
    walker = words;
    while (walker != NULL && *walker != NULL){
        free(**walker); 
        free(*walker);
        free(walker); 

        walker++;
    }

    return bigLatinSentence;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int lengthOfResult = length + count + (count * 2);
```

must be

```
int lengthOfResult = length + count + (count * 2) + 1; /* + 1 for final '\0' */
```

---

```
while (walker != NULL && *walker != NULL){
    free(**walker); 
    free(*walker);
    /* free(walker); Don't do this, you still need walker */
    walker++;
}
free(words); /* Now */
```

---

And you have a leak:

```
int main(void)
{
    ...
    free(result); /* You have to free the return of translateSentence() */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,too. But is it really necessary to free the result ? Because the book I read say that the program clear all the memories when it ends.

Comment: you are welcome, and no, don't trust it, C doesn't have a garbage collector, thats your work, use always valgrind if you are on Unix

Answer (score 4):

Your code is unnecessarily complicated, because you have set things up such that:

- `n`: the number of words
- `words`: points to allocated memory that can hold `n+1` `char **` values in sequence
- `words[i]` (`0 <= i && i < n`): points to allocated memory that can hold one `char *` in sequence
- `words[n]`: `NULL`
- `words[i][0]`: points to allocated memory for a word (as before, 0 <= i < n)

Since each `words[i]` points to stuff-in-sequence, there is a `words[i][j]` for some valid integer j ... but the allowed value for `j` is always 0, as there is only one `char *` malloc()ed there.  So you could eliminate this level of indirection entirely, and just have `char **words`.

That's not the problem, though.  The freeing loop starts with `walker` identical to `words`, so it first attempts to free `words[0][0]` (which is fine and works), then attempts to free `words[0]` (which is fine and works), then attempts to free `words` (which is fine and works but means you can no longer access any other `words[i]` for any value of `i`—i.e., a "storage leak").  Then it increments `walker`, making it more or less equivalent to `&words[1]`; but `words` has already been `free()`d.

Instead of using `walker` here, I'd use a loop with some integer `i`:

```
for (i = 0; words[i] != NULL; i++) {
    free(words[i][0]);
    free(words[i]);
}
free(words);
```

I'd also recommending removing *all* the casts on `malloc()` and `calloc()` return values.  If you get compiler warnings after doing this, they usually mean one of two things:

- you've forgotten to `#include <stdlib.h>`, or
- you're invoking a C++ compiler on your C code.

The latter sometimes works but is a recipe for misery: good C code is bad C++ code and good C++ code is not C code. :-)

---

Edit: PS: I missed the off-by-one `lengthOfResult` that @David RF caught.

Comment: @tork Thanks for your help. I am newbie to C, and I don't really understand when should I add the indirection. The reason I use `char ***` is because I want to calculate the address of `char **`.

Comment: When your pointers start getting complicated and messy, I recommend drawing diagrams on a whiteboard/chalkboard (or paper, if no whiteboard is available).  It takes a while to develop this as a skill too, but it can help a whole lot to have a visual diagram of where the pointers are pointing....

Comment: Oh, I have drawn the picture. I finally understand why you said my code is too complicated, the words `char *` in sequence can be put into sequence and `char **` can be used to reference the first element. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Related to that - whenever possible I would use a different name for different levels of dereferencing; so if you had a pointer to `words`, I might call it `startOfWordPointerBlock`, then have an array of `wordPointers`. Not only does it keep things clean, but you can see immediately that you only want to free your `startOfWordPointerBlock` once, right at the end. It was an interesting exercise to try to debug this. Lesson learnt: when tools exist to do this kind of thing "behind the scenes" - use them.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
while (walker != NULL && *walker != NULL){
    free(**walker); 
    free(*walker);
    free(walker); 

    walker++;
}
```

You need to check that `**walker` is not NULL before freeing it.

Also - when you compute the length of memory you need to return the string, you are one byte short because you copy each word PLUS A SPACE (including a space after the last word) PLUS THE TERMINATING `\0`. In other words, when you copy your result into the `bigLatinSentence`, you will overwrite some memory that isn't yours. Sometimes you get away with that, and sometimes you don't...

Comment: Maybe I read that wrong, but `free(NULL)` is guaranteed to work (and do nothing).

Comment: @delnan it's the same :(

Comment: @delnan you are right - this is a habit from (olden) days when I used "less than standard compliant" compilers and I would be treated to a core dump for not checking. Really, when I see someone free three pointers and testing two of them for `NULL`, my inconsistency alarm goes off.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, so I was intrigued by this, and it took me a while to figure out.

Now that I figured it out, I feel dumb.

What I noticed from running under gdb is that the thing failed on the second run through the loop on the line

free(walker);

Now why would that be so. This is where I feel dumb for not seeing it right away.  When you run that line, the first time, the whole array of char*** pointers at words (aka walker on the first run through)  on the second run through, when your run that line, you're trying to free already freed memory.

So it should be:

```
while (walker != NULL && *walker != NULL){
    free(**walker); 
    free(*walker);

    walker++;
}

free(words);
```

**Edit:**

I also want to note that you don't have to cast from void * in C.

So when you call malloc, you don't need the (char *) in there.

Comment: Damn it looks like folks already beat me to the punch.  Oh well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I understand what you say. But I don't understand why freeing walker the first time and the second time free the same memory !?

Comment: Because free() frees the whole block of memory Pointed to by walker.  So when you call it the first time, it frees the whole array.  Then you do walker++ and point to another element in that array and call free, but the whole array has already been freed.